# Conflict between IPv4 CIDR block for the VPC and recomended CIDR block size

Tags: amazon-web-services, vpc, cidr

From the [AWS VPC docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Subnets.html)

> When you create a VPC, *you must specify* an IPv4 CIDR block for the VPC. **The allowed block size is between a /16 netmask (65,536 IP addresses) and /28 netmask (16 IP addresses).**

Then a few sentences later:

> When you create a VPC, **we recommend that you specify a CIDR block (of /16 or smaller)** from the private IPv4 address ranges as specified in RFC 1918:

```
10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (10/8 prefix)

172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (172.16/12 prefix)

192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (192.168/16 prefix)
```

To me it seems that 2/3 of the recommended block sizes are outside of the allowed range.

What's the deal?

Comment: The 3 blocks listed are IANA RFC 1918 reservations. The VPC docs are not recommending that you use one of these verbatim but that you use a subrange of one of these that fits the VPC requirements (between /16 and /28).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3 blocks listed are IANA [RFC 1918](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1918) reservations. The VPC docs are not recommending that you use one of these verbatim but that you use a subrange of one of these that fits the VPC requirements (between /16 and /28). For example:

- 10.0.0.0/16
- 172.16.0.0/16
- 192.168.0.0/16

Comment: So if I wanted 3 separate VPCs in a single region, then it would be valid to use 10.0.0.0/16, 10.1.0.0/16 and 10.2.0.0/16?

Comment: @Chris Yes, or they could all be 10.0.0.0/16 if you want. The only problem with making them all the same CIDR is if you later intend to peer them. But if they remain independent of one another then it's quite normal for multiple VPCs in an account all to have the same VPC CIDR.

Comment: Thanks @jarmod. The intention would be to peer them actually across regions, now that I think about it.